# counting redundancies in linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm practicing code that can find redundancies in a linked list. 
For example:

INPUT

> 777

OUTPUT

> contains 2 redundancies

INPUT

> 32182

OUTPUT

> contains 1 redundancies

I'm struggling to actually track redundancies in my code. I'v sorted the linked list, then I assume I would just create 2 pointers one that traverses the current location of the linked list and one that traverses the previous location of the linked list and if they're equal count++. But I always get 0 redundancies.

In the code below, I think my challenge is mainly in the countRedun() method.

```
struct digit * insertAtFront(struct digit *start, struct digit * newDig){
    struct digit * ptr = start;
    newDig = start;
    return newDig;

}
struct digit * insertIntoSorted(struct digit *start, struct digit *newDig) {
    struct digit *ptr = start;
    struct digit *prev = NULL;
    while ((ptr!=NULL) && (ptr->num < newDig->num)) {
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if (prev == NULL) {
        start = insertAtFront(start, newDig);
    } else {
        prev->next = newDig;
        newDig->next = ptr;
    }
    return(start);
}

struct digit * sortedCopy(struct digit * start) {
    //! heap1=showMemory(start=348, cursors=[start, ptr, sortedStart, newDigit])
    //! heap2=showMemory(start=519, cursors=[start, newDigit, ptr, prev])
    struct digit *ptr = start;
    struct digit *sortedStart = NULL;
    struct digit *newDigit;

    if (start!=NULL) {
        sortedStart = createDigit(start->num);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    while (ptr!=NULL) {
        newDigit = createDigit(ptr->num);
        sortedStart = insertIntoSorted(sortedStart, newDigit);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return(sortedStart);
}

int countRedun(struct digit * start){
    struct digit  *sorted, *ptr, *prev, * curr;
    ptr = start;
    prev = start;


    //sort linked list
    sorted = sortedCopy(start);
    int count = 0;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {

        if(ptr->num == prev->num)
        {
        count++;
        }
    prev = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    }

}
```

I've excluded the code that asks user for input, as well as the linked list creator methods, assuming that the sorting, and counting methods are key for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like sortedCopy makes a whole new list, but sorted.  If so, then you need to reorder:

```
ptr = start;
prev = start;


//sort linked list
sorted = sortedCopy(start);
```

with:

```
//sort linked list
sorted = sortedCopy(start);
ptr = sorted;
prev = sorted;
```

as a note, you would likely be better to:

```
 prev = NULL;
 while(ptr != NULL) {
    count += (prev && ptr->num == prev->num);
    prev = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

otherwise you count will always be off by one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in `insertAtFront`

```
struct digit * insertAtFront(struct digit *start, struct digit * newDig){
    struct digit * ptr = start;
    newDig = start;
    return newDig;
}
```

Remember that everything is passed by value.  Your `ptr` variable isn't used at all, and in this function `start` and `newDig` are local variables.  Really this is equivalent to:

```
struct digit * insertAtFront(struct digit *start, struct digit * newDig){
    return start;
}
```

Have another look at that function.  I'm not sure of your context but you can use a debugger or printf statements to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that:

- all you need to do is get the number of redundancies
- your input is always going to be a digit between `0` and `9`

Then you don't need to sort the data (which, by the way, you're doing in O(n^2) time complexity).

All you need to do is keep an array with 10 elements initialized to `0`, increase the corresponding index to your element and count the elements with value greater than `1`.

Something along the lines of this (beware: NOT tested):

```
int countRedun(struct digit * start){
    int counter[10] = {0};
    struct digit *ptr = start;
    int total = 0;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        counter[ptr->num]++;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (counter[i] > 1) {
            total += counter[i] - 1;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```